# Get all the properties of object that is underlying in an object

Tags: c#-4.0, properties, system.reflection

```
    class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeId;
        public UserGroup[] UserGroups;
        public Department Department;
        public List<Address> Address;
    }
    class UserGroup
    {
        public int GroupId;
        public string GroupName;
        public string UserName;
        public string Password;
    }
    public class Department
    {
        public int DeptId;
        public string DeptName;
    }
    public class Address
    {
        public string Street;
        public string ZipCode;
        public decimal Latitude;
        public decimal Longitude;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method should loop and read all the properties of Employee object and and assign value to that property
    /// Ex: if propertyName is EmployeeId, propertyValue must be assigned to it.
    /// Ex: if propertyName is GroupName, propertyValue must be assigned to it.
    /// Ex: if propertyName is DeptName, propertyValue must be assigned to it.
    /// Ex: if propertyName is Latitude, propertyValue must be assigned to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    /// <param name="propertyValue"></param>
    public static AssignValueToProperty(Employee obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        //Implementation Pending
    }
```

Given the Employee object, PropertyName and PropertyValue, I should be able to loop through all its internal object's properties and assign values to that property. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can access object properties using reflection in **C#.NET** and also `get` and `set` values to that property.

I think you are looking for something like this.

Considering your given `Employee` object which is

```
    class Employee
    {
        public string EmployeeId;
        public UserGroup[] UserGroups;
        public Department Department;
        public List<Address> Address;
    }
```

You want to loop through the all properties of the object. You can do it like following:

```
Employee objEmp = new Employee();

//loop

foreach(var property in objEmp.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   AssignValueToProperty(objEmp, property.Name, "{Your Value}");
}
```

Then in your `AssignValueToProperty` Method you would have something like

```
public static AssignValueToProperty(Employee obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    objEmp.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(objEmp, propertyValue, null);
}
```

Moreover I would like to add is you have the object structure having properties like `UserGroup[] UserGroups` Where `UserGroup` is another object. Don't you think your `AssignValueToProperty` method wont work here because it is accepting property values as string datatype while you have different datatypes in you `Employee` object. So all you have to do is loop through multiple objects properties like the way given above and finally set them into employee object.

You can set the object by checking their `datatypes` as well. ***i.e.***

```
foreach(var property in objEmp.GetType().GetProperties())
{
   // Get PropertyType
   string datatype = property.PropertyType.Name;
   // Apply conditions on the datatype basis
   if (datatype.Equals("string") && property.Name.Equals("EmployeeId"))
   {
      // assign string values
      objEmp.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(objEmp, "{your string value}", null);
   }
   else if (datatype.Equals("UserGroup") && property.Name.Equals("UserGroups"))
   {
      // assign object value
      objEmp.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(objEmp, "{your UserGroup Object}", null);
   }
   // so on other properties
}
// And Finally Use `objEmployee` with all properties values set.
```

**BONUS**

You can also find and set property using lambda expression like following:

```
objEmp.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("{PropertyName}") && x.PropertyType.Name.Equals("{Target datatype}")).FirstOrDefault().SetValue({Your Object}, {Your Value}, null);
```

In case if you need to create a class object at runtime then method definition would be as follows:

```
public static AssignValueToProperty(string obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(obj, true);
    object objEmp = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    objEmp.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(objEmp, propertyValue, null);
}
```

Hope That Helps... :)

Comment: In this scenario, there will be four functions for the four classes that Sri created. Is there a way to handle these all classes with this single method. I mean that we do not restrict the class  "Employee" in the method "AssignValueToProperty" and use this method for all the classes.

Comment: As per my assumptions, you want to write a dynamic function through which we can create instance of any class under a namespace and set its properties through reflection, like we already doing above. In order to do that, you may please try Type type = Type.GetType("Employee", true);object objEmp = Activator.CreateInstance(type); Hope that helps.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a new method definition as well.